# Operations on Strings

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to write code for the following string operations:

1) to reverse a string.
        This is what I have:

```
 String rev = ""; 
        String reverse(String s){
            if(s.length() == 1){
                return s; 
           } 
           else {
                rev += s.charAt(s.length()-1)
                        +reverse(s.substring(0,s.length()-1));
                return rev;
            }
        }
```

2) If two strings are equal to each other.

```
  int compareString(char a, char b, int n){
        if (n == 0 || a == 0 || a != b){
           return a - b;
         }
        else {
           return(compareString(a+1, b+1, n-1));
        }
     }
```

3) if a string is a palindrome (for example, "eye" or "racecar") - reads the same forwards and backwards.

```
boolean checkPalindrome (String s){
        if(s.length() == 0 || s.length() == 1){
            return true; 
        }
        if(s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(s.length()-1)){
        return checkPalindrome (s.substring(1, s.length()-1));
       }
        return false;
    }
```

I am unclear on 2. As an exercise in recursive thinking,  I would prefer only recursion techniques and corrections for the above. Thank you.

Comment: If you're only unclear on part two, that should be the only thing in the question. Now how do you expect to compare two *strings* when you're only providing two *characters*?

Comment: Please use the proper tags for the questions only. For example, code above belongs to Java and not to C#. If you want/need a response in C# or another language, please post such question in the desired language.

Comment: Part 1 - you should move `String rev = "";` inside the method (see what happens when you call `reverse()` twice).

Comment: And *I am unclear* is not a solvable problem. Tell us what works and what doesn't (with actual data examples) and **ask specific questions**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If two strings are equal to each other.

When comparing two strings, you have to pass in the strings.

```
public static boolean isEquals(String a, String b) {
   if (a.length() != b.length()) return false;
   return isEquals(a, b, 0);
}

private static boolean isEquals(String a, String b, int index) {
    if (index >= a.length()) return true;
    if (a.charAt(index) != b.charAt(index)) return false;
    return isEquals(a, b, index + 1);
}
```

or if performance doesn't matter

```
public static boolean isEquals(String a, String b) {
   if (a.length() == 0)
       return b.length() == 0;
   if (b.length() == 0)
       return false;
   return a.charAt(0) == b.charAt(0) &&
       isEquals(a.subString(1), b.subString(1));
}
```

Comment: If performance doesn't matter is a *very* true statement for 2nd option, because `substring` copied the underlying array in Java 8.